# Out of memory issue in gensim topic modeling

Tags: gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I wanted to successfully run LDAseq model on my very huge corpus. I finally want to extract 100 topics from it.

I am getting an error "out of memory" on the step of ldaseq model. This is because I have a huge token and I don't want to truncate it. How to resolve this memory issue?

- Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
- Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
- NumPy 1.17.0
- SciPy 1.3.0
- gensim 3.8.0
- FAST_VERSION 0

My expected result is the same as shown in the documentation. I need a topic-term and topic-doc matrix finally.

Answer (score 0):

Use on the MMCorpus of **gensim.corpora.MMcorpus**
It's similar to UCI Bow easy to build.
https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/mmcorpus.html